# `.append()` does not work for dynamically added components

Tags: jquery, dom

```
if( $("#mce_21-body").append($("#color").html()))
{
   console.log("appended");
}
else 
   console.log("failed");
```

Here `

```
    <div id="#mce_21-body">...</div>
```

dynamically created element.  condition says appended but no appending happened here.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn how to format code and text in general.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#mce_21-body")` always returns a jQuery wrapper object which will be always truthy, to check whether the element actually exists you can check the length

```
if ($("#mce_21-body").append($("#color").html()).length) {
    console.log("appended");
} else {
    console.log("failed");
}
```

or

```
var body = $("#mce_21-body");
if (body.length) {
    body.append($("#color").html())
    console.log("appended");
} else {
    console.log("failed");
}
```

Comment: Thank u it actually not yet created i think .I have no idea how code it

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        if( $("#mce_21-body").length)
        {
            $("#mce_21-body").append($("#color"));
            console.log("appended");
        }else {
            console.log("failed");
        }
```

Comment: i tried it actually console shows "failed".I want to add element after  this element ready, But i failed to do that could you please suggest me any methods?